# Facing an error while trying to get a .csv column

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to display one column of a .csv file in Neo4j. Here in the content of .csv file:

```
site,IP
ex1.com,10.10.10.10
ex2.com,11.0.0.0
```

I use this query:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///file.csv' AS row
WITH row[1] AS ip
RETURN ip
LIMIT 3
```

but I get this error:

```
Expected Long(1) to be a org.neo4j.values.storable.TextValue, but it was a org.neo4j.values.storable.LongValue
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Can you show (at least the first few lines) of your CSV file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you specified the `WITH HEADERS` option, you should access the file's data fields using the appropriate header names instead of using indexing (e.g., `row[1]`). *Indexing would just give you strange results or errors because the software would try to treat the header row like any other row.*

For example, this query should work just fine:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///file.csv' AS row
RETURN row.IP AS ip
LIMIT 3
```