# connect multiple nodes to a single node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm really new to Neo4J. I have a .csv file with these columns:

```
address,ip
add1.domain.com,1.1.1.1
add2.domain.org,2.2.2.2
add3.domain.org,3.3.3.3
```

I want each line to be a node. All these nodes should be connected to a single node (which represents the domain node). I have written this code:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///file.csv' AS row
WITH row[0] AS sub, row[1] AS ip
MERGE (p:sub {sub: sub})
  SET p.ip = ip
CREATE (d:domain{name: "domain.com"})
CREATE (p)-[r:related_to]->(d)
RETURN count(p)
```

Then I used this query to display the nodes:

```
MATCH (p:sub)-[rel:CONTAINS]->(d:domain)
RETURN p, rel, r
```

but I found out that each row of the file (each node) is separately connected to the domain node 2 times. Look at this:

[image: neo]

What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: FYI: you modified the question by adding a row to the CSV file, but did not change the visualization (which no longer shows the expected full results from your query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First of all, you should either get rid of the header row in your CSV file, or use the header names in your query. See [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60131796/974731).*

Your main issue was the usage of `CREATE` to create the `domain` node and the `related_to` relationship. Due to the usage of `CREATE`, every row of the data file would create a new node and relationship. And the same thing would happen every time you re-ran the same query. (You probably ran the query twice, which would cause the results you saw.)

You should start from scratch and try using this query:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///file.csv' AS row
MERGE (p:sub {sub: row.address})
SET p.ip = row.ip
MERGE (d:domain{name: "domain.com"})
MERGE (p)-[r:related_to]->(d)
RETURN count(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you might also want to create some indices. The name for the domain and the address (property sub) for sub is assumed to be of unique value. That way, you don't come up with duplicate nodes. Let's also create the domain node here.

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Domain(name);
CREATE INDEX ON :Sub(sub);
MERGE (:Domain {name: "domain.com"})
```

In you model you use related_to and contains, but I assume a `(:Sub)-[:RELATED_TO]->(:Domain)` path here.

Depending on how many rows you have, you might want to use periodic commits.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///files.csv' as row
MERGE (p:Sub {sub: row.address, ip: row.ip})
MATCH (d:Domain {name: "domain.com"})
MERGE (p)-[:RELATED_TO]->(d)
```

To check that everything worked, just run `MATCH path=(:Domain {name: "domain.com"})--() RETURN path` to see everything directly connected to the domain node.